# Handling Local notifications

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uilocalnotification

I want to handle the local notifications in iphone sdk 3.0. Is there any way to achieve the same? I know how to handle it from 4.0 onwards. Please suggest me on how to handle the same in the sdk's below 4.0

Thanks,
Manjunath

Comment: UILocalNotifications are not available in SDK's below 4.0, so you cannot use them in earlier iOS SDK's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UILocalNotifications* are introduced in `iOS 4.0` and *Push Notifications* are introduced in `iOS 3.0`. If you want to implement notifications for the versions `iOS 3.*` you should go to *Push Notifications*.

Apple's [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) may help you to move on further.

Comment: @Manjunath, I like Simson, but I am not him :-)

Answer (score 0):

UILocalNotifications are not available in SDK's below 4.0, so you cannot use them in earlier iOS SDK's.

Comment: I already mentioned that I know how to do it in 4.0 but my doubt was how to achieve the same in sdk's below 4.0